# Center DIV NOT working

Tags: html, css, center

I'm trying to simply center div inside of another div.
I read on another post that as long as the width of the div im trying to center is smaller then the container width, and `margin: 0 auto;` is set, it should center and thats not the case with my code below. I need help

my container

```
#main {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

the div im trying to center inside my container

```
#tablesection { 
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `display:inline-block`

Comment: why would i need to do that if what they said was true, and the table inside the div is a block by default

Comment: it's working proper.. check this https://jsfiddle.net/s6dvszg9/

Comment: that was copied straight from my code its working on jsfiddle but not on my file with the same code. -_-

Comment: @GullyBoy i've no idea what post your talking about and `inline-block` is not the same as `block`. alot of the time in my work when i'm trying to center a `div` the answer has been to make it into an `inline-block`

Comment: i just added a border and its not working also...i also tried same file on another computer in here...could it be a format issue

Comment: go and google it else come here with your code.

Comment: the exact same code does in fact now work now in jsfiddle but not on my site with same code...maybe its the text wrangler program im using...when i used #for id it doesnt work in head tag in style section but when i put same code in as a inline style it works but now my table is not even displaying correctly.im done with it thanks guys. had it up to here with these quirks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#outer{
   background-color: #000;
   float: left;
   height: 200px;
   width: 100%;
   }
#centerDiv{
   background-color: #fff;
   height: 150px;
   margin: auto;
   width: 70%;
}
```

check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tojopaul/hfqtrkam/2/).

Answer (score -1):

sorry guys BIG rookie mistake...had another css declaration in my style section with a closing bracket missing that caused all of that.
its crazy how one bracket can cause all that random behavior

so that CODE DOES in FACT work.thanks for the help guys it feels good to know its a whole community like this to help noobs like me

Comment: yes. Recheck your code before post .. thanks

Comment: yea i see lost my whole ranking...thought this site was to help ppl not make them scared to ask another question

Comment: @GullyBoy - Don't take downvotes personally, they simple measure how useful (or not) a post is. For a typo like this, you could just delete the question. You get your rep back as well.

Comment: @misterManSam: As I understand it, the OP *can't* delete a question with multiple answers (or one upvoted answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
#main {
width:1200px;
height:800px;
margin: 0 auto;
border-radius: 6px;
background:red;
}
 #tablesection { 
   width:600px; 
   border:1px solid;
   margin:0 auto;
   background:green;
}
```

its working